# How do I display Japanese characters in Atom.io?

Tags: localization, atom-editor

Does anyone use Atom with foreign characters (e.g. Japanese). I found [one post on this](https://discuss.atom.io/t/japanese-encoding/17871), but no one had replied.

Is there a package to install or something? I have Japanese Anthy installed, so I can type Japanese characters in other programs (LibreOffice, Chrome, etc), and I'm saving in UTF-8. Just in Atom these characters appear as squares.

Answer (score 1):

This was a [known bug with Atom (Issue #7899)](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/7899), and has been fixed in newer versions, please check your atom version and upgrade if necessary.